# Redeem Google Checkout coupon on Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps, google-checkout

Are Google Checkout coupons redeemable on Google Play?

I've created a coupon on Google Checkout for a paid Android App on Google Play but when trying to buy it as a user, I can't find the place to enter it. On one device I saw a "Redeem" option along with the credit card but when I entered my coupon code, it returned an error message. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Unfortunately, coupons are not supported with Play Store..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use coupon codes with Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to use Promo Codes now. It's kind of hidden but it's there. Just find the app you want to buy in Google Play and click the buy button and continue until you get to the Payment Options window. Now click the "Pay With:" dropdown and select "Redeem Google Play Gift Card or Promo Code". You'll now have a box for entering Promo Codes.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: Google Play Payment Window] [image: Google Play Promo Window]